# CVXOPT QP: ignores constraint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cvxopt

I'm trying to solve a QP problem using cvxopt.
There are two constraints

> 0<=y<=b 
>   wy=0

So I define

```
p=np.diag(-np.ones(len(myset))
```

`p1=np.diag(np.ones(len(myset)))`

```
dd=np.concatenate((p,p1),axis=0)
```

which are two identity matrix, which allow me to define:

> -y<=0

I also write

```
v=np.concatenate((zero,b),axis=0)
```

in which 'zero' is an array which has the dimension (len(set),1) and also b, and are respectively my lower and upper bound for the variable y. 
I define G and h:

```
G=matrix(dd)
h=matrix(v)
```

But when I print the solution the values for y are also negative, so it ignores completely the constraint which impose to y to be positive.
Could someone help me please?

I printed the matrix G,h and A,b and were chacaracterized by all zero values, so there's an error in the definition of these matrix?